# android - cannot find symbol class ActivityRegisterBindingImpl

Tags: java, android

i trying to use pattern MVVM in android but i facing to a problem.
when run my project i facing this error(Log Android Studio):

```
cannot find symbol class ActivityRegisterBindingImpl.
```

when i go to see class of have problem ,i go to class ActivityRegisterBindingImpl.

so in class DataBinderMapperImpl ,can founding

```
import com.example.questionandanswer.databinding.ActivityLoginBindingImpl;
```

but can't founding this:

```
import com.example.questionandanswer.databinding.ActivityRegisterBindingImpl;
```

this is modelView:

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import android.view.View;

import com.example.questionandanswer.model.RegisterUser;

public class RegisterViewModel extends ViewModel {
    public MutableLiveData<String> name = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<String> EmailAddress = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public MutableLiveData<String> Password = new MutableLiveData<>();


    private MutableLiveData<RegisterUser> currentName;

    public MutableLiveData<RegisterUser> getUser() {
        if (currentName == null) {
            currentName = new MutableLiveData<RegisterUser>();
        }
        return currentName;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {

        RegisterUser registerUser = new RegisterUser(name.getValue(),EmailAddress.getValue(), Password.getValue());

        currentName.postValue(registerUser);

    }
```

}

Comment: are they in the same package/module/... ?

Comment: yes both of them are in the package of viewModel

Comment: are you sure you're looking into the correct version?

Comment: i don't understand about correct version. can explain that? correct version what ?

Comment: After implemting databinding for an activity. Rebulid the project. it will pick up your files.

Comment: you say the method is there, the jvm says it isn't. maybe you are looking in a different version of that library than the jvm is

Comment: @ Hashir Saeed : i can't rebuliding my project becuse is see this : Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. LoginViewModel is missing it file:/home/ramtin/Desktop/QuestionAndAnswer/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_register.xml loc:32:33 - 32:46 ****\ data binding error ****

Comment: that is "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0" version library of viewmodel. in your idea what i use from other of version ?